# Как настроить open server для скачанного с интернета сайта написанного на php?

Tags: php, openserver

Скачал папку с сайтом, написанным на php из github и хочу посмотреть что там. Каким образом могу открыть его локально?

Comment: с начало вообще изучите что такое сервер `apache`. и как поставить его на ваш компютер.

Comment: я поставил опен сервер

Comment: но что дальше? предполагаю, что нужна БД, но как создать подходящую?

Comment: для этого читайте в гите где скачали как сделать настройки, если там есть, если нет ройтесь в коде и найдите настройки `mysql`.

Comment: естественно там нет, иначе бы ни у кого времени не отнимал)

Comment: в каких файлах хотя бы нужно рыться?

Comment: там где настройки примерно `dbname` или что то подобное, смотря как автор сделал настройки, посмотрите если ли папка или файл `config`.

Comment: Обычно в описании авторы пишут как развернуть их сайт у себя. Кстати, ссылка на гитхаб была бы не лишней.

Comment: https://github.com/KoalaMoala/BlablaCar

Comment: Буду признателен, если поможете открыть

Comment: https://github.com/andkamarauskas/Vamos

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы определить, что Вы скачали. Необходимо для начало взглянуть на то, что скачали. Дальнейшие действия определяются в зависимости от файлов в папке и от расширений файлов. Например, если вы скачали верстку сайта, она будет иметь расширение `.html`. В такой папке, обычно в корне находится файл `index.html`. Его и запускайте. Если у Вас присутствуют файлы с расширением `.php`, сайт необходимо запускать на сервере.

Comment: файлы с расширением .php поэтому создал папку в опен сервер. сейчас хочу создать БД с соответствующим названирем, но какая будет кодировка и хватит ли этого для открытия сайта?

Comment: Сейчас чаще всего используется кодировка `utf-8 general ci`. Это касаемо `phpMyAdmin` в `Open Server`. Вижу у Вас уже получилось открыть.

Comment: Общий принцип в принципе один. Открыв и запустив один такой сайт Вы уже будете знать какие-то файлы и за что они отвечают.

Answer (score 0):

1) Скачивает `OpenServer` - устанавливаем

2) В папке `domains` создаем папку (например `blabla.localhost`) и туда переносим то что вы скачали.

3) Запускаем `OpenServer` там находим `phpMyAdmin` и создаем там новую БД, например `blabla_db` (просто создать БД без таблиц)

4) Идем по пути `domains/blabla.localhost/application/config/database.php`, находим и изменяем строчки:

```
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'blabla_db',
```

5) Запускаем: http://blabla.localhost - все должно работать

---

P.S. После первого запуска таблички в БД сами создадутся, ибо в проекте настроена миграция.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81507/discussion-on-answer-by-manitikyl---open-server----).